# Why is confusion & diffusion not required PKI encryption schemes like Elgamal encryption?

Tags: block-cipher, elgamal-encryption, pki

The Elgamal encryption scheme is a Multiplicative Mask with the shared key. It doesn't seem to have any confusion or diffusion.

So why is it not necessary here as compared to Block Ciphers?

Comment: If you at [Shannon's confusion diffusion paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion#Theory) `confusion refers to making the relationship between the ciphertext and the symmetric key as complex and involved as possible; diffusion refers to dissipating the statistical structure of plaintext over the bulk of ciphertext`. These are design goals. You expect from Elgamal designed as a block cipher but it is not. It has CPA security by design. AES-ECB doesn't but it has good diffusion-confusion, confused? In short, diffusion-confusion is necessary but not sufficient...

Comment: @kelalaka - why is confusion & diffusion required only for block ciphers & not for PKI encryption like Elgamal?

Comment: Sorry, indeed the Elgamal achieves conf&diff but one needs to show it!.

Comment: I think calculations over a group do provide diffusion. I think it is an interesting question and I hope that somebody that is more mathematically inclined can show this in an answer.